# What does this notation in minimal square error mean?

Tags: statistics, mean-square-error

My book defines minimal square error as:

$$MSE(\theta, T) = E_\theta\Vert T - \theta \Vert^2$$

What does the $E_\theta$ mean? Is it an expectation? If yes, what does the theta supscript do there?

Comment: The "expectation under $\theta$" indicates that the distribution of $T$ is parametrised/indexed by the unknown parameter $\theta$. That is, the expected value depends on $\theta$.

Comment: Thanks. So in fact it can be left out?

Comment: It is a notational convention. So not writing the subscript $\theta$ does not matter theoretically. In fact, one can also write $MSE_{\theta}(T)$ for the MSE.

Answer (score 0):

The notation $E_\theta$ usually means expectation taken over the values of $\theta$, i.e. $$
E_\theta \|T-\theta\|^2 = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \|T - \theta\|^2 \, p(\theta)\, d\theta.
$$

But here I think the writer is being sloppy and means $$
E_{T|\theta} \|T-\theta\|^2 = \int \|t - \theta\|^2 \, p(t|\theta)\, dt.
$$

Comment: This doesn't match the comment above though.

Comment: Assuming $T$ is the estimator and $\theta$ is the parameter, it should be $\int ||t-\theta||^2 p_{\theta}(t)\,dt$.

Comment: You are integrating out the true value of $\theta$. So $MSE(\theta,T)$ is saying what the average squared error of an estimation rule "$T$" is, where the average is taken over the possible true values of $\theta$ according to their relative probability.

Comment: @ted Do you agree that $E(g(T))=\int g(t)p(t)\,dt$ where $p$ is the pdf of $T$?

Comment: Actually, here the notation could mean $\int \|t_n - \theta\|^2 \, p(t_n|\theta) \, dt_n$. This is a notational shortcut though. I would have written it as $E_{T_n|\theta} \|T_n - \theta\|^2$.